# Ubuntu 14.04 Amd Catalyst drivers installation

Tags: ati, fglrx

Following [this guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide#Installing_Proprietary_Drivers_a.k.a._Catalyst.2Ffglrx) I'm trying to get AMD Catalyst drivers installed using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

But I'm getting...

```
kayl669@kayl669-pc:/usr/share/ati$ sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Being very new to Ubuntu I'm meeting a lot of frustration when trying to install things where it seems that there are dependencies which won't install for this reason. Perhaps somebody could suggest a general procedure to follow to get past this type of issue. What is the problem in general terms - a conflict or corruption?

I'm actually using Lubuntu and my goal is to get a dual-monitors setup working.

What should I try next in this instance? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I already had a suitable driver. I just needed to use the xrandr command to expand my desktop across two monitors.